# Make supermethod stop implementated method

Tags: java, methods, types, initialization

I have a class called `TileEntity` which has a method `updateEntity()` which gets called every "tick". I'd like to make an implementation of it skipping certain ticks, so I thought about making a pattern class which has `updateEntity()` which automatically counts for me and just `return;` if it's not the right tick. Will my whole `updateEntity()` method stop if I call the superclass, or will it just continue with the normal method? `updateEntity()` isn't a `boolean`, so I can't check returns.

Comment: Hey Pwnie, please post some code showing what you've tried so we have a starting point.

Comment: This is completely incomprehensible. As trojansdestroy says, post some code, your actual issue, your desired outcome, and stack traces if applicable.

Comment: Your task is not clear.

Comment: What is the type of your "tick"? (int or enum or something else?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @keshlam said, calling `super.myMethod()` is like calling any other method.

So you shall use template method as:

```
public final void updateEntity() {
    if (checkTheTick()) {
        doUpdateEntity();
    }
}

protected void doUpdateEntity() {
    ... // the original implementation of updateEntity goes here
}
```

now you can override `doUpdateEntity` and call the `super.doUpdateEntity()` and check for the right tick.

Comment: Yep. Thought about suggesting that refactoring of the problem, but thought it might be too obvious to be worth mentioning. Thanks for filling in the gap.

Answer (score 3):

If you call super.updateEntity(), that's like any other method call -- when it returns, it returns to the method which invoked it.